# Passing attribute into shader Libgdx

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, glsl, shader

I can't figure out how to pass a custom attribute into the shader using libgdx. I have a float inside my shader:

```
attribute float a_ParticleStartTime;
```

I want to pass in the current time into my shader at the time of creation. I have my mesh, and can use it to specify color and position like such:

```
 mesh = new Mesh(true, MAX_VERTS, 0, 
                    new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, POSITION_COMPONENTS, "a_position"),
                    new VertexAttribute(Usage.Color, COLOR_COMPONENTS, "a_color"));
```

But I'm lost on how to pass in an attribute that is not a default catergory in the Usage class. I need to pass in the current time. Does anybody know the correct way to do this? I looked at examples but found nothing. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For VertexAttribute, the Usage parameter, to my knowledge, is ignored since Libgdx doesn't support OpenGL ES 1.0 any more.

So just add one more attribute with generic usage to your mesh.

```
mesh = new Mesh(false, MAX_VERTS, 0, //for a mesh that you're updating frequently, false is theoretically better (but maybe not in practice on most GPUs)
    new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"),
    new VertexAttribute(Usage.Color, 4, "a_color"),
    new VertexAttribute(Usage.Generic, 1, "a_ParticleStartTime")); //The 1 is because it's a single float
```

When you are putting or updating vertices in your float array to use with `mesh.setVertices`, you now have 8 floats per vertex: `x, y, z, r, g, b, a, startTime`